# How to upload a file and show progress bar in Django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, progress-bar

I have written code to upload a file in Django as follows:

```
def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        return render_to_response('uploadsuccess.html')
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()  
return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})


def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    filename = "/media/Data/static/Data/" + f.name
    destination = open(filename, 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

The code works fine for me. However, I don't know how should I modify this code to show a progress bar on the client side.

My html page looks like:

```
{% extends "index_base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<script src="/media/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  src="/media/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
<div id="main_container">

{% include "includes/nav.html"  %}

<!------- Main Contents  ---------->
    <div id="contents_holder">
        <div id="contents">
            <div id="c_banner">
                    <span class="main_title">Upload File</span>
                </div>
            <div id="setting">
            <form name="post" action="/upload.psp/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h2>Upload File</h2></br>
                <p>{{ form.file.label_tag }}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ form.file }}</p></br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="uploadButton" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancelUploadButton" onclick ="cancelUploadClicked()"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="title" name="title" id="title" />
            </form> 
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!------- Main Contents  Finished ---------->
{% endblock %}
```

Can anybody help me integrate Upload progress bar with this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to send an asynchronous request using Ajax.

The topic is also discussed here: [File upload progress bar with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)
and here: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)